# How do I remove the mo creature's cat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I've been having this problem since I first downloaded the mod last year. I've tried shifting and I've seen a suggestion to try breeding them for the chance that the cat on your head is the female and will go to the bed, didn't work.

The only way I've been able to get them off my head (accidentally picking them up when trying to put food in the beds and breeding, etc) is going to the title screen. When I shift, I get the little pop noise to indicate that the cat is off my player's head, but the feet and belly are still in my face.

This doesn't happen with any other animals, just the cat. Is there a way to fix that, or is it just a bug that came with the mod?

I'm playing in 1.12.2 Java if that helps

Comment: This question is not asking for *technical* support.